# Error Including QGeoPositionInfo

Tags: c++, qt, gps

I am new to Qt ,

I have been given this task where i should use GPS

so to use to GPS ,i only did this one line of code

```
 #include <QGeoPositionInfo>
```

and the following error appeared

```
In file included from ..\Project\mainwindow.cpp:3:
..\Project\/form.h:7:28: error: QGeoPositionInfo: No such file or directory
```

how can i solve this issue ? how can i get this file ?

please note that i have tried re installing Qt Creator...

**Please be specific i would really appreciate that...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGeoPositionInfo` is part of [Qt **Mobility**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/index.html#introducing-the-new-qt-apis), which is an extension to Qt.

Comment: See the linked webpage. It's got an installation guide.

Answer (score 1):

in .pro file add:

```
{CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY +=location}
```

2:in header add:

```
{using namespace QTMobility}
```