# Retrieving the position of the phone using GPS in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gps

I want to know the longitude and the latitude of the phone, and for that I must use the `QtLocation` library.

For best results, which class and function should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Including QGeoPositionInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956785/error-including-qgeopositioninfo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information comes from the Qt Mobility class QGeoPositionInfoSource. You will find an example [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Retrieve_Location_Using_Qt_Mobility).

Comment: You'll even find an example [on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956785/error-including-qgeopositioninfo)